# Minecraft PE (Android) parameters

Tags: java, android, minecraft, android-package-managers

I have tried to develop my "first" application as Minecraft launcher, because my son has more than 300 worlds and scrolling worlds is terrible slow and very often he accidentally start different world.

Then I would like to show him list of worlds, it's working now.  I have name extracted from `level.dat` and directory where is world.

I would like to add functionality to start Minecraft with world selected from my app.

This should be as:

```
Intent mcintent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mojang.minecraftpe");
mcintent.putExtra("world","name of world"); // this not working
startActivity(mcintent);
```

Parameters for `putExtra` is fiction, I need to know real parameters to start Minecraft and immediately open selected world.

Any suggestions would help.